# AVAudioPlayer does not give error but not playing sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avaudioplayer

Hello I am completely new to apple development

i run the code on my iPhone there is no error but i can not hear the sound
  here is the code

```
-(void) buttonPressed1:(UIButton *)sender{  
    NSString *fileName = @"Record_000";
    NSLog(@"%@", fileName);
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];
    self.theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:NULL];
    self.theAudio.volume = 1.0;  
    [self.theAudio prepareToPlay];
    [self.theAudio play];
}
```

this is my h file

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface StartPage : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
@end
```

Comment: add an NSError *error and replace self.theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error]; in this way you can catch the error with NSLog("error = %@",error);

Comment: but i am not getting an error jest the i push the button and there is no sound

Comment: @user3218241- have u connected the button action with button

Comment: only if i change the name of the audio file to 1 that not exist i get error

Comment: yes button connected and i can see the NSLog every time i push the button

Comment: Have you added Record_000.wav to app bundle resources? Log the path string, to see if it is not null.

Comment: @user3218241- also check if your hardware have speaker and volume

Comment: NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Record_000" ofType:@"wav"];
NSLog(@"%@", Path);

Comment: i log the path it is not null it give a path to the file

Comment: On what device are you running the app, and what is iOS version?

Comment: i can here sound on my iPhone but not from my app

Comment: NSURL* fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: fileName withExtension:@"wav"];

Comment: no now fileURL give the same result

Comment: Have you tried another audio file?

Comment: i now try mp3 file i download from the internet not working

Comment: another audio file not working as wall

Comment: Did you tried the suggestion from @Ilario? Log the error, and tell what you have

Comment: i put try and catch but there is no error so it does not go to the catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the audio session:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioSession.h>

    -(void) viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        [self setAudioSession];
    }

    -(void) setAudioSession
    {
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        NSError *sessionError = nil;
        BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
        if (!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Setting Audio Session Category Error: %@", sessionError);
        }
        success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&sessionError];
        if (!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Setting Audio Session Active Error: %@", sessionError);
        }
    }
```